# Exporting Cognito Form to PDF

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I export a Cognito Form that I've built into PDF format?

If I print the screen it prints the entire screen as opposed to just the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to print to pdf you could try going to the public url of your form and using your browser print to pdf as your destination printer.  I know the Chrome Browser has a print to pdf option but this option would only work for simple 1 page forms I believe.

We do have the feature "[PDF & Word Merging](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy)" on the next up section of our idea board that I think would cover what you are trying to do. I don't know at the moment of this feature would allow for saving a blank form as PDF but it seems reasonable that it would.

I'll see if I can get clarification on that feature.